# Terraform data source giving resource not found error even the resource exist in the cloud

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-private-dns-zone

I was calling a data source in side terraform code.

```
data "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "acr_service" {
  name                = "privatelink.azurecr.io"
  resource_group_name = "it-aue1-cor-arg-privatedns"
```

This resource and resource group already exist in the cloud. still i am getting resource not found error.

Comment: Can you add the error to the question as well?

Comment: Hai, I figured out the issue. I was trying to call data source from another subscription and the provider alias of that subscription was not provided. Now I added it and it worked.

Comment: Could you post an example? I added provider alias to data source but still getting the error.